# Knockout js table row click breaks radio button click binding

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to figure this issue out.  I have a table with a number of rows bound to a view model in `knockout`.

The idea is that a row can be selected.  There is a radio button to indicate the selection.  However, in this scenario, when I click the row, the radio button becomes selected - as I hoped.  However, when the radio button is clicked, it does not select itself.

This is achieved using a table row click binding.

```
<tr data-bind="click: $parent.doSelect.bind($parent, $data);">
```

This causes an issue with the radio selection.  You can see the bound values are set, but for some reason the radio button selection will not change.

How can I have both means of selection to play nicely?

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andez2000/a1ys2upo/95/)

**html**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th>Col A</th>
    <th>Col B</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- ko foreach: { data: items, as: 'item' } -->
    <tr data-bind="click: $parent.doSelect.bind($parent, $data);">
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="selectMe" data-bind="checkedValue: Id(), checked: $parent.selectedItemId" />
      </td>
      <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </tbody>
</table>

<p>
  You have selected <span data-bind="text: selectedItemId"></span>
</p>
```

**javascript**

```
function MyViewModel() {

  this.selectedItemId = ko.observable(null);

  this.items = ko.observable([{
      Id: ko.observable(1),
      Name: ko.observable("Dave")
    },
    {
      Id: ko.observable(2),
      Name: ko.observable("Bob")
    },
  ]);

  this.selectedItemId.subscribe(function(itemId) {
    console.log("selectedItemId.subscribe: fired for " + itemId);
    var self = this;
    _.forEach(this.items(), function(item) {
      if (itemId == item.Id()) {
        // need to set something here
      }
    });
  }, this);

}

MyViewModel.prototype.doSelect = function(item) {
  var itemId = ko.unwrap(item.Id);
  console.log("doSelect: " + itemId);

  this.selectedItemId(itemId);
};

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function `doSelect` you must return `true` otherwise the event will not bubble up.

```
MyViewModel.prototype.doSelect = function(item) {
  var itemId = ko.unwrap(item.Id);

  this.selectedItemId(itemId);

  return true;
};
```

See KO [documentation](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note-3-allowing-the-default-click-action) for this.

> However, if you do want to let the default click action proceed, just return true from your click handler function.